# Insert TextView to Firebase

Tags: android

How can i put the text of TextView into a Firebase database?

"count" is the TextView.

Maybe the wrong is "String dt=txtdistance.getText().toString();"

```
//Insert Data to Firebase
    txtlocation= findViewById(R.id.search);
    txtdistance=findViewById(R.id.count);
    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref=mDatabase.getReference().child("location");

    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String lc=txtlocation.getText().toString();
            String dt=txtdistance.getText().toString();
            DatabaseReference mRef=ref;
            mRef.child("location").setValue(lc);
            mRef.child("distance").setValue(dt);

            startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this, Filter.class));
        }
    });
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. unless your question is regarding android studio as an IDE, there's no need to add the tag for it in your question. your code wouldn't be any different in another IDE

Answer (score 1):

@George Sepetadelis Here is all my `Dasboard` code.

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView count;
private SeekBar seek_Bar;

Button bt;
EditText txtlocation, txtdistance;
DatabaseReference ref;
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;


@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    //seekbar
    count = findViewById(R.id.count);
    seek_Bar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seek_Bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            i = progress;
            count.setText(""+i+" χλμ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    //Insert Data to Firebase
    txtlocation= findViewById(R.id.search);
    txtdistance=findViewById(R.id.count);
    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref=mDatabase.getReference().child("location");

    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String lc=txtlocation.getText().toString();
            String dt=txtdistance.getText().toString();
            ref.child("location").setValue(lc);
            ref.child("distance").setValue(dt);

            startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this, Filter.class));
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all please explain what is not working correctlly.

If your problem is when the data was not sent to the database try to make something like this:

```
ref.child("location").setValue(lc);
ref.child("distance").setValue(dt);
```

I think when you can't set as value on a `DatabaseReference` variable a value of other `DatabaseReference` variable

Comment: txtlocation= findViewById(R.id.search);
String lc=txtlocation.getText().toString();
mRef.child("location").setValue(lc); 
This text (EditText) i can send to the Firebase.

String dt=txtdistance.getText().toString();
txtdistance=findViewById(R.id.count);
mRef.child("distance").setValue(dt);
This text (TextView) i can't send to the Firebase.

Comment: @Thanoskol you getting any errors from the firebase or something like this on the catlog?. If not, try to do what i told you above on my reply. (περιμενω απαντηση σου ;-)  )

Comment: No errors in catlog or somewhere else and your code above isn’t still work (ευχαριστώ)

Comment: Do you know how to send the TextView into the Firebase Database ? Any tips or video that it would be useful ?

Comment: @Thanoskol i will make an app like yours and i will try to see what is going wrong with the code and i will come back to tell you where is the problem :-) (btw make sure when your rules on your real-time db it looks something like that 



`{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}`

(sorry for the bad format)

Comment: My rules on my real-time db is {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}.
 I'm waiting for you to tell me if you found my mistake ;)

Comment: @Thanoskol I can't find any mistake on your code. Can you put all the code when you have on your `Dashboard` activity inside  your question ??

Comment: I wrote it below @George Sepetadelis

Comment: @Thanoskol try to check if your value when you set on database is not null with a simple if statement (`if (ls == null || dt == null){μπλα μπλα μπλα}`)

Comment: Isn't working :( Give me an example if you want :/ @George Sepetadelis

Comment: @Thanoskol `If(ls == null || dt == null){System.out.println("value is null"); })` if this part of code prints on the logcat this message, means when the values of the 2 variables is bull :~)